# How to merge more than 1 cell value with a comma in a single cell of a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-group-concat

I have a 2 tables in SQL Server in which there are multiple locations for a name, all I need to do is to club locations into one cell for that names.

```
Table 1
Name
H
I
J

Table 2
Name Location
H    Delhi
H    Mumbai
H    Hyderabad
I    Chennai
I    Delhi
```

Now after applying join the result should be as follows

```
Name Location
H    Delhi, Mumbai, Hyderabad
I    Chennai, Delhi
```

Please help me out in this asap.

Comment: Use looping that add location for each first capital query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just realised that u need two tables just a few alteration in the code, check the code below

```
    Create table #temp1
    (
    Name varchar(10) 

    )

    Create table #temp2
    (
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(100)
    )

    Insert into #temp1
    values ('h' ),('I' )

    Insert into #temp2
    values ('h','delhi'),
    ('h','Mumbai'),
    ('h','Hyderabad'),
    ('I','Chennai'),
    ('I','Delhi')

    Select *from #temp1
    Select *from #temp2



    select t.Name,
        STUFF((   SELECT ', ' +te.Location
            FROM #temp2 te
            WHERE T.Name = te.Name
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,1,'') as Location
    from #temp1  t
    group by t.Name 


   DROP TABLE #temp1;

 DROP TABLE #temp2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this code , You can use the xml path for concatenation purpose

```
              DROP TABLE #temp;
    Create table #temp
    (
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(100)
    )

    Insert into #temp
    values ('h','delhi'),
    ('h','Mumbai'),
    ('h','Hyderabad'),
    ('I','Chennai'),
    ('I','Delhi')

    select t.Name,
        STUFF((   SELECT ', ' +te.Location
            FROM #temp te
            WHERE T.Name = te.Name
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,1,'') as Location
    from #temp  t
    group by t.Name
```

Result Set

Name    Location

h    delhi, Mumbai, Hyderabad

I    Chennai, Delhi

Comment: @SAK HI sak I dint add the create temp table command it kindly check now.. or do u getting any errors please let me know